# PUPPETEER_DOWNLOAD_HOST is deprecated. Use PUPPETEER_DOWNLOAD_BASE_URL instead. / Puppeteer windows 11

Tags: javascript, npm, puppeteer

i tried to install puppeteer , i followed installation guide.

but after few seconds , it shows me this error:

```
.../node_modules/puppeteer postinstall$ node install.mjs
│ PUPPETEER_DOWNLOAD_HOST is deprecated. Use PUPPETEER_DOWNLOAD_BASE_URL instead.
│ ERROR: Failed to set up Chrome r119.0.6045.105! Set "PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD" env variable to skip download.
│ Error: Download failed: server returned code 404. URL: https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/119.0.6045.105/win64/chrome-win64.zip
│     at file:///C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/WorkSpace/Projects/test/Server/node_modules/.pnpm/@puppeteer+browsers@1.9.0/node_modules/@puppeteer/browsers/lib/esm/httpUtil.js:74:31
│     at ClientRequest.requestCallback (file:///C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/WorkSpace/Projects/torob/Server/node_modules/.pnpm/@puppeteer+browsers@1.9.0/node_modules/@puppeteer/browsers/lib/esm/httpUtil.js:52:13)
│     at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:629:26)
│     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:514:28)
│     at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (node:_http_client:693:27)
│     at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:119:17)
│     at TLSSocket.socketOnData (node:_http_client:535:22)
│     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:514:28)
│     at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:376:12)
│     at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:349:9)
└─ Failed in 5.1s at C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\WorkSpace\Projects\test\Server\node_modules\.pnpm\puppeteer@21.6.0\node_modules\puppeteer
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
```

after some research i found out that using  `npm config set puppeteer_skip_chromium_download true`  might fix the problem but when i tried it , it showed me this:

```
npm ERR! `puppeteer_skip_chromium_download` is not a valid npm option
```

my node version: 20.9.0

npm version: 10.2.4

yarn version: 1.22.19

pnpm version : 8.11.0

(i used npm , yarn and pnpm)

note:
Puppeteer-core can installed without any problem .

Comment: What is `node install.mjs`? You don't need to go into `node_modules` and run commands. Puppeteer [should install Chromium automatically with `npm i puppeteer`](https://pptr.dev/#installation): "When you install Puppeteer, it automatically downloads a recent version of Chrome for Testing (~170MB macOS, ~282MB Linux, ~280MB Windows) that is guaranteed to work with Puppeteer". "i followed installation guide" -- which one?

Comment: I tried it , and shows me the same error. And CLI was in project folder not in node_modules directory. I used this guide: https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the [Official Docs](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.configuration), I found this solution: create a `.puppeteerrc.cjs` file in the project's root folder and add this:

```js
/**
* @type {import("puppeteer").Configuration}
*/
module.exports = {
    // Changes the cache location for Puppeteer.
    downloadBaseUrl:"https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing",
};
```